# Como puedo agregar el editor latex a mi sitio?

Tags: javascript, html

¿Alguien sabe como puedo agregar el editor latex en mi sitio web?, por ejemplo, que cuando yo escriba una ecuación en un input, me la previsualize, o que cuando se detecte palabras en formato latex me las convierta a el mismo?, perdonen por no explicarme bien, he estado viendo este artículo, pero no me ha servido de nada :/
https://www.rubenapaza.com/2017/06/ecuaciones-latex-mathjax-katex-pagina.html
Algo como el siguiente editor:
https://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php
Hasta ahora solo consigo lo siguiente :/ que es lo que está en la parte del contenido ($-x$)
[image: Captura del resultado]

Comment: ¿Podrías ajduntar el codigo que has intentado? Tambien en mathjax se ocupan \\( \\), en vez de ocupar $ $, para abrir y cerrar codigo en linea.

Comment: No hay problema, solo metí los scripts de latex dentro del head, tal como lo dice en el tutorial, pero cuando recargo mi sitio, no carga sino que se queda en blanco

Comment: Este es todo mi head:

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.11.1/dist/katex.min.css" integrity="sha384-zB1R0rpPzHqg7Kpt0Aljp8JPLqbXI3bhnPWROx27a9N0Ll6ZP/+DiW/UqRcLbRjq" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- The loading of KaTeX is deferred to speed up page rendering -->
    <script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.11.1/dist/katex.min.js" integrity="sha384-y23I5Q6l+B6vatafAwxRu/0oK/79VlbSz7Q9aiSZUvyWYIYsd+qj+o24G5ZU2zJz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

Comment: Eso lo saqué del sitio oficial

Comment: Prueba poniendo en el body: <p> \\( - x \\) </p>. Y usa el primero que sale en https://katex.org/docs/autorender.html.

Comment: Ya lo intenté, pero no

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una forma de añadir un render para formulas de LaTeX es ocupando Katex.

En el ejemplo, haremos que se haga render automático de cualquier formula del body. Esto se explica en https://katex.org/docs/autorender.html

Para colocar una formula en linea, se ocupa `\( formula \)` en vez de `$ formula $` y, para formulas display, se usa `\[ formula \]` en vez de `$$ formula $$`, pues es el estandar de LaTeX: [FAQ-dolldoll](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-dolldoll).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.11.1/dist/katex.min.css" integrity="sha384-zB1R0rpPzHqg7Kpt0Aljp8JPLqbXI3bhnPWROx27a9N0Ll6ZP/+DiW/UqRcLbRjq" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.11.1/dist/katex.min.js" integrity="sha384-y23I5Q6l+B6vatafAwxRu/0oK/79VlbSz7Q9aiSZUvyWYIYsd+qj+o24G5ZU2zJz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.11.1/dist/contrib/auto-render.min.js" integrity="sha384-kWPLUVMOks5AQFrykwIup5lo0m3iMkkHrD0uJ4H5cjeGihAutqP0yW0J6dpFiVkI" crossorigin="anonymous"
    onload="renderMathInElement(document.body);"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Podemos colocar formulas en linea, por ejemplo, \(-x\).</p>
    <p>O, por ejemplo, \(\int \cos^2(x)\,dx\).</p><br>
    <p>También podemos colocar en forma de display math:\[\int \frac{1}{x}\,dx\] y se colocará en el centro.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```